# Python3 Parsing

Tags: python, парсер

Имею задачу:
Распарсить строку (просто пример):

```
'6.6/2.2*(1-0.5)'
```

в:

```
['6.6', '/', '2.2', '*', ['1', '-', '0.5']]
```

Знаю, что это можно сделать каким то образом с помощью `pyparsing.Forward.parseString`, но как, понять не могу.
Как работать с этим методом, что передавать, как вызывать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
S = '6.6/2.2*(1-0.5)'

signs = ['/', '+', '*', '-', '(', ')']

def pars_expr(S):
    IN = False
    IN_OPTS = False

    res = []
    tmp = []
    opt = []

    for i, item in enumerate(S):

        if item == '(':
            IN_OPTS = True
            continue

        if not IN_OPTS:
            if item not in signs:
                IN = True

            if IN and item not in signs:
                tmp.append(item)
                if i == len(S)-1:
                    res.append(''.join(tmp))
            if IN and item in signs:
                IN = False
                res.append(''.join(tmp))
                tmp = []

            if not IN and item in signs:
                res.append(item)
        else:

            if item not in signs:
                IN = True

            if IN and item not in signs:
                tmp.append(item)
            if IN and item in signs:
                IN = False
                opt.append(''.join(tmp))
                tmp = []

            if item == ')':
                IN_OPTS = False
                res.append(opt)
                opt = []
                continue

            if not IN and item in signs:
                opt.append(item)


    return res


print(pars_expr(S))
```

Это если не хотите пользоваться библиотеками